# How te display SSRS report on Android devices

Tags: android, reporting-services, report

Is it possible for an android device to contact a SQL Server Reporting Service and retrieve a report, and then display this report?

I've to build an app that can do that, but I'm not even sure it is possible.

Thank you for help (and sorry for bad english)

Josh.

Comment: HI josh, there is no such a mobile application that open the ssrs reports. But you can open ssrs report in android's mobile default browser, only you have to add some CSS code in your report server. use this link for refrence http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/12/ssrs-show-ssrs-reports-properly-in.html

Comment: that's what I feared. Not being able to open report in an application instead of a web browser.. Thank you for your answer, I'll investigate :)

Comment: no sure, there are the ssrs web services. you can call them from any app, no problem

Comment: Yes I can call them, and I will get the report, but how can I display that report on the screen (without having to open a web browser) ?
That's where I struggle :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reinventing the wheel you should probably look at something like Forerunner which takes care of the backend interaction with Reporting Services so you can use HTML5, JSON etc. and the usual app development standards.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/771341/Reporting-Services-for-iPhone-Android-and-all-othe

https://forerunnersw.com/home/index

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm doing an intership in a company, and I can't use existing tools like forerunner.. sadly ..

Comment: You can try and just use an existing browser, e.g. Chrome or Firefox, which may or may not work but Android is not a supported platform for any browser for rendering SSRS reports (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx ("Browser Requirements for Viewing Reports"). You can try and build an app to interact directly with the SSRS web service - I'm no Android expert but I suspect that will be a lot of work.

Comment: One option you might look at is calling the web service to render the report as PDF and then displaying the PDF on screen?

Comment: That would be a solution, indeed :)
I have read somwhere that I can use a WebView to display the report. Maybe that's what i'am looking for